# How to integrate mongodb with solr using mongo connector?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, solr

I already have my Solr configured and running in the port 8983. Initially i indexed all the data in the MongoDB using data import handler. But now I realized that for every update and new insertion to automatically index we need a Mongo connector . I followed these links: [Mongo Connector](http://blog.mongodb.org/post/29127828146/introducing-mongo-connector) and [Usage-with-Solr](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Usage-with-Solr).

I am getting struck at the point

```
python mongo_connector.py -m localhost:27017 -t http://localhost:8983/solr
```

It shows error

> python: can't open file 'mongo_connector.py': [Errno 2] No such file or directory

how to integrate a collection named food with the mongodb collection testfood such that new insertions and update automatically reflects in solr.

Comment: Is the mongo_connector.py file in the current directory when you run the command?

Comment: no it isn't i am unable find where it is located

Comment: How did you install the connector?

Comment: using this pip install mongo-connector

Comment: The guide on [Github](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector)  runs the connector as `mongo-connector` (no python or .py as you did). Have you tried that? The blog post you linked to is quite dated

Comment: haven't tried that link going to try it now

Comment: Tried that link but nothing happens